# Why is JavaScript referred to as Client Side Technology?

Tags: javascript, web

JavaScript can interact very well with the server also. Using Ajax we can send and receive xml requests too. So Why it is known as Client Side Scripting Language and not Server Side?

Comment: Because it **runs** on the client side

Comment: Ajax requests are executed on client side also. They only *interact* with the server side, you said it yourself

Comment: And for the sake of completeness, Javascript can also be used as a server-side technology. See [node.js](http://nodejs.org) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because for historic reasons javascript was first created to run in a web browser and web browsers usually run on the client. Today there are frameworks like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) which allow for running javascript on the server.

> Using Ajax we can send and receive xml requests too.

Yes, those requests are sent from the client.

Answer (score 1):

Server Side languages are those that process data on the server. PHP for example only renders a page(as HTML, XML) and sends this to the user. After this, the page is in the client's browser. The serverside script cannot control the page once it has been sent.

Javascript runs on client side, it can access the page and change its elements and stuff, but it cannot access the server that sent it. When I say access, I mean it cannot run any functions directly on the server. It can only interact with the server if the server allows it to(via ajax).

Also, the user(client) can modify the javascript on a page using browser extensions(Chrome Debugger), firebug, but it cannot access the server side script. He cannot change what the PHP code for example. The client side script has only that much access to the script that the server allows it to have.

Answer (score 0):

The final stroke:

JavaScript was a servside technology. And it was a part of a quite famous technology called ASP. Those days developers could do programming in either vbscript or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It was developped for Netscape in the [middle of the 90's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#History) to be run on this browser. A few years later _ long before nodeJS - it was also able to run on a server, thouht 99% of its use is probably still in the browser.